# how to open a url from the barcode scanner in phonegap build

Tags: phonegap-build, barcode-scanner

i'am using the Barcode Scanner for phonegap build, How would i retrieve the QR Codes URL data and display the webpage into a Iframe or div

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#scanner_mode").click(function() {

    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );

});
});
```

Right i have tried this but its not working, so how would i get the src of a iframe to load `result.text` url

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#scanner_mode").click(function() {

    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
              document.getElementById("frame").src = result.text; 
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }

   );

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep so its working :)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#scanner_mode").click(function() {

    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
              document.getElementById("frame").src = result.text; 
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }

   );

});
});
```

that works :)